# How to close fading in bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap model in which i tried to close it using

```
$('#editmodel').modal('hide');
```

but with the this the fadding still remains ,can anyone please suggest help.

My html,

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editmodel" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content" *ngIf='student'>
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 *ngIf='showonadd' class="modal-title">Add New</h4>
      <h4 *ngIf='showonupdate' class="modal-title">Edit -{{student.accountname}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" >

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">FirstName:</label>
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)] = 'student.accountname' class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>


        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)='insertdata(student)'>{{buttonname}}</button>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am using a bootstrap model in which i tried to close it using

```
$('#editmodel').modal('hide');
```

but with the this the fadding still remains ,can anyone please suggest help.

Answer (score 2):

This: `<div class="modal fade" id="editmodel" role="dialog">`

To

This: `<div class="modal" id="editmodel" role="dialog">`

The **fade** class is adding fading effect please remove this class and try.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1688/) here.

Comment: even after removing it

Comment: can you please create a JsFiddle for it

Answer (score 0):

Edit your .fade class to this.

```
.fade {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: none;
-o-transition: none;
transition: none;
}
```